# Rangy function highlightSelection performance

Tags: javascript, rangy

Why rangy becomes more sluggish when the number of annotations made ​​with function `highlighter.highlightSelection` (marktype) is growing?
Performance is very good at first but this decreases as they grow annotations.

so,How could I do to improve the performance of the function `highlighter.highlightSelection()`? because  when I  were selected many different parts of my html  the performance worsens exponentially. if you select a fragment  of html very  long the performance is going to be worst. I tried to fix this but i had not known how.

Anyone know why this might happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance degrades because Rangy has to remove and recreate all existing highlights whenever a new highlight is created. This inefficiency is one reason why the highlighter module has never been included as an official Rangy module.

I'm working on a different, character offset-based approach that may improve performance, so there is hope.

Comment: thanks, when this version will be ready? is important to me, thanks for your work!!

Comment: @Martin: I'm hoping to have something ready in the next week or so.